# Producing a subList from a vector<int> in C++

Tags: c++, stl

is there a built-in STL method to do that?

In java, there is list.subList(a,b) for extracting [a,b). Similar method in STL C++?

Answer (score 20):

Sure.

```
std::vector<int> subList(&originalVector[a], &originalVector[b]);
```

Comment: That's nice, but using iterators would be even more general!

Comment: @Kerrek SB - Pointers _are_ a kind of iterator, and this _is_ the vector-from-iterator constructor that's being called. There's no way to get an iterator (the kind returned by `vector::begin()`) to an arbitrary point in a `vector`, is there?

Comment: @Chris: `originalVector.begin() + a` will do, and that'll work on all random-access containers :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: The requirement is only for `vector`. So YAGNI.

Comment: @DeadMG are you saying that the begin()+a will only work for vector?

Answer (score 16):

You can do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> x;

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        x.push_back(i);
    }

    // Here we create a copy of a subsequence/sublist of x:
    std::vector<int> slice_of_x(x.begin() + 3, x.begin() + 7);

    assert(slice_of_x.size() == 7-3);
    assert(slice_of_x[0] == 3);

    return 0;
}
```

This will make a copy of the requested part of `x`. If you don't need a copy and would like to be more efficient, it might be preferable to pass around iterator (or pointer) pairs. That would avoid copying.

Comment: so that's one advantage of using iterators, and by extension the vector template in general.

Comment: is anybody serious here? I cannot find either of these functions!

Comment: `slice_of_x` isn't a function, it's creating a new instance using a constructor that takes an iterator range

Comment: it's one of vectors constructors `slice_of_x` is the name of the new vector.

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

```
std::vector<int> subList(originalVector.begin() + a, originalVector.begin() + b);
```